# How to hide standard libs in Godoc?

Tags: go, godoc

I usually started the GoDoc server using "godoc -http=0.0.0.0:6060" for sharing document with stuffs. The prob is it always mix built-in libs' doc with my application's. After some search that std lib hiding feature seems not supported this moment.. (please correct if wrong)

So, is there any hack can help to hide the std libs?

Or to ask in different way, is there a way to select path / package to show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, but you can always use the package path and send the url, for example:

```
http://localhost:9020/pkg/github.com/OneOfOne/xxhash/
```

Comment: Any reason for the -1?

Comment: @OneOfOne: someone on this question is -1 happy.  I +1'd to cancel it out ;)

Comment: still wondering why I have not figure out this simple and working solution, LOL..

Comment: Basically, the templates are in http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/godoc/static, modify
those files and then run go generate, and rebuild godoc. I think because of that we're not able to hide the standard libraries.